# Custom Executable for Source engine games?

Tags: source-engine, valve

I'm just wondering how source games have their own executables?

For example, Portal 2 has portal2.exe, LF42 has left4dead2.exe, Garry's Mod has a hl2.exe that displays gmod icon and has Facepunch Studios etc. in its metadata.

Comment: If you have the source code for a game engine you may build your own exe just like you would build an exe from any other C++ code. I'm sure that's what Portal 2 and Left 4 Dead 2 are doing because those are Valve's own games. For Garry's Mod it might not be the same answer.

Comment: @Romen Can do it with SDK ?

Comment: I believe the Source SDK is meant for making mods for games. So you use the exe from the game you are modding.

Answer (score 1):

**Altering the "hl2.exe" Icon**

- Create your Icon (has to be 256x256p) and save it as an interlaced
  .png
- Find a .ico converting website and make convert the .png to .ico
  (*Gimp* Is a free Image editing application that can also save as
  .ico)
- Download and save the .ico in"\steamapps\sourcemods\MODNAME\resource"
  as "game.ico"

Now It should display your Icon, If not then restart your PC

*More about Source Engine Icons can be found at:*
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Making_Icons_and_Integrating

These steps can also

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it at least summarized the steps from the tutorial, so even if a reader can't find that document, they can make progress by reading the information in your post.